# JPQL: How to rewrite postgres native query to JPQL query that uses filter keyword

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpql

Im trying to avoid using native query. I have this query that uses the filter function, how could I rewrite this to not use that and work in regular jpql?

```
 @Query(
    "SELECT time_bucket(make_interval(:intervalType), d.time) as groupedDate, " +
      "CAST(d.team_Id as varchar) as teamId, CAST(d.service_Id as varchar) as serviceId, CAST(d.work_id as varchar) as workId, " +
      "ROUND(CAST(count(d.value) filter ( where d.type = 'A') AS numeric) /" +
      " (CAST(count(d.value) filter ( where d.type = 'B') AS numeric)), 4) as total " +
      "FROM datapoint d " +
      "WHERE d.team_Id = :teamId and d.service_id in :serviceIds and d.work_id = :workspaceId and d.type in ('A', 'B') " +
      "AND d.time > :startDate " +
      "GROUP BY groupedDate, d.team_Id, d.service_Id, d.workspace_Id " +
      "ORDER BY groupedDate DESC",
    nativeQuery = true
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

in the FROM statement you have to use the DAO object instead of the table name